# Create hexadecimal number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, unique-key

I want to generate unique hexadecimal numbers in SQL. How can I do this?

If you know how to generate in c# please also include that.

Comment: I feel the need to point out... a hexadecimal number is just like a decimal number. They're numbers. The only difference is how you decide to represent or display it.

Comment: I agree with Tom's comment. There seems to be some sort of misunderstanding here... Why is it that you need a number in hexadecimal form?

Comment: Its user requirement that we should auto generate a HexaDecimal number as unique ID not an integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQL Server**:

```
SELECT  NEWID()
```

**Oracle**:

```
SELECT  SYS_GUID()
FROM    dual
```

**MySQL**:

```
SELECT  UUID()
```

In **PostgreSQL**, you'll have to use an external function, though it has `UUID` type.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server: newid()

In C#: System.Guid.NewGuid()

These get you [GUID's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guid), which are unique, hexidecimal numbers; however, they tend to have dashes (-) in the middle of them, so you may have to do a bit of string parsing to get what you want.  Other than that, though, this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an integer IDENTITY column and then a conver that to hex using

```
CONVERT(varbinary(8), MyTable.MyId)
```

Comment: Should be varbinary(8).  Also, question for the OP: This gets you a unique number for that table.  If you just want a unique hex number to identify a row in a table, go with this one--lot easier to manage and type in for manual queries.